# How do I edit PDF annotations made by macOS Preview?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, pdf, macosx, annotation

In macOS High Sierra's Preview I drew a rectangle on a PDF. In Lubuntu 18.04's Document Viewer, I see only the ability to add text or highlight, but the rectangle appears inaccessible as if background on the PDF.

It seems to me that Okular enables me to draw a line, but not to edit the rectangle. (I have installed it from Lubuntu's Software.)